# Ajax request being submitted multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Im working on fixing some validation to my forms. The validation works, problem is that when  no validation error occur, the form submits as many times the user tried to submit. It is like the requests stacks up on a pile.

Forms has this submit button that calls my ajax function `create_new_stuff`

```
<input id='submitButton' onclick='create_new_stuff()' name='submit' type='submit' value='create' />
```

The function

```
function create_new_stuff(){

    $("#createForm").submit(function(event){       

        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = false;

        var input_value = $("#createValue").val();

        if(input_value === "" || null){

            console.log("Wrong input value");
            return;
        }
        else{

            var request;
            var $form = $(this);
            var serializedData = $form.serialize();

            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/new_stuff.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData              
            });

            // callback handler that will be called on success
            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

                console.log("Stuff created!", response);             
                create_new_stuff_form();
                var successDiv = $("<div class='success'>Stuff was created</div>");
                $("#responseMessages").html(successDiv);

            });

            // callback handler that will be called on failure
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                console.error(
                    "The following error occured: "+
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );

            });          
        }         
    });
}
```

Comment: Could it be cause you have an onClick event on a submit type button? Try switching your button type from `submit` to `button`.

Comment: After Successful validation you can disable the submit button and make the server call Or show some loading image in the place of button.. and treat as per server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of adding **onclick** event to submit button, add **onsubmit** event to form.

```
<form onsubmit= 'create_new_stuff()'>
</form>
```

Comment: This did the trick, and in combination to skip the `$("#createForm").submit(function(event){}` function and just do the stuff straight in `create_new_stuff(event)` function

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id='submitButton' onclick='return create_new_stuff()' name='submit' type='submit' value='create' />
```

And return false when you don't want to submit the form from your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Change button type submit to button or change onclick to onsubmit

Comment: @Bullfinch  You submit the form nothing more than you would like to submit data to the server。 You can use $.ajax do it.

Answer (score 0):

Prevents the event from bubbling up by:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on Submit button the onclick calls the create_new_stuff() method to do the required stuff. If you think to do this on form submit or button click both shall show the same behaviour. You can try something like this:

> HTML

```
<label for="formelement">Enter Value Here:</label>
<input type="text" id="formelement" name="formelement">
<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Submit">
```

> JS

```
$("#submitbutton").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#submitbutton').attr('disabled',true);
var x = $("#formelement").val();
  if(x=="" || null)
{
    console.log("Wrong Input..!!");
    return;
}
else {
    console.log("Hello" + " " +x);
}
});
```

> Working Demo :  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2VGN7/1/)

And you can put a loader here to show server action being done.!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution specifically for the situation when you are trying to use same code for different forms and you have to use separate function for form submission instead of direct submission 
   `$("#this_is_form_id_string").on('submit', function(e){ });`

you can do the trick

```
function submit_forms(form_id){

   var avoid_duplicate_form_submission = 0;      

    $("#"+form_id).submit(function(e){           
       e.preventDefault();  

         avoid_duplicate_form_submission++;

         if(avoid_duplicate_form_submission === 1){

                    // All your code....  
            }

    });    

}
```